# Adventure for CJ Carella's Armageddon RPG

Tags: published-adventures, unisystem

I'm looking for Adventures for CJ Carella's Armageddon RPG, as I really like the system much. Sadly, there's nothing to buy out there. Do you have recommendations which other adventures could fit into the background or where I can find an adventure online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system is the same one used for Witchcraft, All Flesh Must Be Eaten, Terra Primate, Conspiracy X, and Beyond Human. Small variations in CGen and paranormal powers, but the same core system.

A streamlined version of it is used for Ghosts of Albion, Buffy the Vampire Slayer, Angel, and Army of Darkness.

Since you like the mechanics, any and/or all of these can be ported.

There are adventures in the series "Eden Studios Presents" for most of them. Vol 1 has a new monster for "Witchcraft and Armageddon"; there is little more for Armageddon in issues 2 & 3, per se, but given the compatibility...

That said...

There is a pair of sourcebooks for it: Enemies Archived, and Armageddon: Armed Force. They are available print on demand or via [DriveThruRPG.com](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/index.php?cPath=77)

Given the subject matter, Terra Primate, Witchcraft, Conspiracy X, Buffy, Angel, Army of Darkness, and AFMBE can all be ported in with little difficulty.